# Why access modifiers in classes defined in methods

Tags: java, oop, access-modifiers

What's the point of using **access modifiers** on the fields of classes which are defined inside methods ?

e.g.:

```
class Outer
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    // class defined inside method
    class Test
    {
      // applies an access modifier
      public int field;
    }

    Test test = new Test();
  }
}
```

Are my following 2 statements correct:

- Regardless of the access modifier, still **the only way to access the field from outside the scope of this method, is using reflection**.
- Regardless of the access modifier, **the field can always be accessed inside the scope of the method**, even when the field is private without any need of reflection.

What strikes me is, that while it's impossible to use an access modifier for the class, it is perfectly applicable to its members. Although neither one of them seems to make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

> Regardless of the access modifier, still the only way to access the
>   field from outside the scope of this method, is using reflection.

Correct.  However if you encounter this issue then the class really shouldn't be a local class.

> Regardless of the access modifier, the field can always be accessed
>   inside the scope of the method, even when the field is private without
>   any need of reflection.

The use cases for local classes are few and far between.  Access modifiers don't really have any impact since your class should be local to the method that created it:

> Like member classes, local classes are associated with a containing
>   instance, and can access any members, including private members, of
>   the containing class.

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_11.htm

**Edit:**

It may seem strange that the compiler allows you to specify a modifier that it then doesn't enforce.  I can think of 2 good reasons why this might be the case:

1. There is a standard class format regardless of the scope of the class.
2. It allows you to show how you intend the member to be accessed, it would probably be a bad idea to access private fields/methods even though it's not syntactically wrong to do so.

Comment: Imho this doesn't answer the question which i am reading as: why does the compiler allow to have access modifier for field members in local classes?

Comment: Regarding 1) - it makes sense to me as well. Just a bit of clarification from the link you provided: 

Local classes cannot be declared public, protected, private, or static.**These modifiers are for members of classes; they are not allowed with local variable declarations or local class declarations.**
Your Test class is local variable and adheres to rule above just like every other local variable definition